# Reverse Geocoding with Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, reverse-geocoding

I'm currently working on a Worklight Project that deals with location based services. I want to be able to get the ZipCode of an user's current location for the iOS platform specifically. I researched online and there are many ways to approach this. I currently have it implemented using a custom cordova plugin using native location manager features and retrieve the zip code through reverse geocoding. This approach seem like I'm doing it the long way. I noticed that google provides an api call for the reverse geocoding by just supplying the lat and long. However, there is a limit to how many calls you can make.

Users of the free API:
2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
10 requests per second.
Maps for Business customers:
100,000 requests per 24 hour period.
10 requests per second.

This app needs to have no restrictions on how many times it can get the location based on zip code.

Does Worklight have a simpler or better way of getting the zip Code for user's location(I've checked the worklight api reference calls but didn't see anything about retrieving user's zip code)?

Comment: AFAIK the answer is "no". You'll need to opt to using your Cordova plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight provide a way to implement this by using adapters, but not the API itself. Although you could the adapter to work as something like a local cache of the ZIP you already know.

To save money due to the APIs that would be usually based on a number of calls, we would need to have some cache, database(more likely: CouchDB or mongoDB) to handle this cache of what you already know.

A mobile(app-side) solution + a server side solution. On putting this 2 together, worklight would help you.